# Selenium Python TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This code ran mostly fine before I inserted the WebDriverWait line. The problem all along is that the dataset is distorted, which I believe is because the data I want to scrape is "below the fold".

I introduced the WebDriverWait line so that the script will click the arrow to unfold the product profile, hence exposing the data I want to scrape. (Everything "above the fold" scrapes fine.)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

data = []

for y in range(1,3):
    website = f'https://www.knowde.com/b/markets-personal-care/products/{y}'
    path = '/Users/kdavid3mbp/Python/chrome_driver64/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    driver.get(website)
    
    for x in range(1,37):
        products = driver.find_elements('xpath', f'//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[{x}]')

        for product in products:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', './div/div/svg'))).click()
            
            brand = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[1]').text
            item = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[2]').text
            inci_name = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[2]').text
            try:
                ingredient_origin = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[3]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                ingredient_origin = 'null'
            try:
                function = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                function = 'null'
            try:
                benefit_claims = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                benefit_claims = 'null'
            try:
                description = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[3]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                description = 'null'
            try:
                labeling_claims = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                labeling_claims = 'null'
            try:
                compliance = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[6]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                compliance = 'null'
            try:
                hlb_value = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                hlb_value = 'null'
            try:
                end_uses = product.find_element('xpath', '/a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                end_uses = 'null'
            try:
                cas_no = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                cas_no = 'null'
            try:
                chemical_name = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                chemical_name = 'null'
            try:
                synonyms = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[6]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                synonyms = 'null'
            try:
                chemical_family = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                chemical_family = 'null'
            try:
                features = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[7]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                features = 'null'
            try:
                grade = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                grade = 'null'

        dict = {
            'brand': brand,
            'item': item,
            'inci_name': inci_name,
            'ingredient_origin': ingredient_origin,
            'function': function,
            'benefit_claims': benefit_claims,
            'description': description,
            'labeling_claims': labeling_claims,
            'compliance': compliance,
            'hlb_value': hlb_value,
            'end_uses': end_uses,
            'cas_no': cas_no,
            'chemical_name': chemical_name,
            'synonyms': synonyms,
            'chemical_family': chemical_family,
            'features': features,
            'grade': grade
        }

        data.append(dict)
        print('Saving: ', dict['brand'])


# Closes driver once for loop is completed
driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('/Users/kdavid3mbp/Python/cosmetics_data.csv', index=False)
```

The current error is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/90/82_f843n4h9drvxh7z3tqg840000gn/T/ipykernel_34523/974946269.py in <module>
     18 
     19         for product in products:
---> 20             WebDriverWait(product, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', './div/div/svg'))).click()
     21 
     22             brand = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[1]').text

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     93             if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94                 break
---> 95         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     96 
     97     def until_not(self, method, message: str = ""):

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000106e946b8 chromedriver + 4937400
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000106e8bb73 chromedriver + 4901747
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000106a49616 chromedriver + 435734
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000106a8ce0f chromedriver + 712207
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000106a8d0a1 chromedriver + 712865
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000106a80ae6 chromedriver + 662246
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000106ab103d chromedriver + 860221
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000106a809c1 chromedriver + 661953
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000106ab11ce chromedriver + 860622
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000106acbe76 chromedriver + 970358
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000106ab0de3 chromedriver + 859619
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000106a7ed7f chromedriver + 654719
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000106a800de chromedriver + 659678
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000106e502ad chromedriver + 4657837
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000106e55130 chromedriver + 4677936
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000106e5bdef chromedriver + 4705775
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000106e5605a chromedriver + 4681818
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000106e2892c chromedriver + 4495660
18  chromedriver                        0x0000000106e73838 chromedriver + 4802616
19  chromedriver                        0x0000000106e739b7 chromedriver + 4802999
20  chromedriver                        0x0000000106e8499f chromedriver + 4872607
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81308d1d3 _pthread_start + 125
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff813088bd3 thread_start + 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the complete solution, I hope you find it useful.

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

data = []

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for page in range(1, 3):

    website = f'https://www.knowde.com/b/markets-personal-care/products/{page}'
    driver.get(website)

    print(f"---------------------- page number: {page} ----------------------")
    if page == 1:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()

    products = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-cy="product-card"]')

    count = 0
    for product in products:
        if count == 0 or count == count+4:
            product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[data-testid="icon-icomoon--keyboard_arrow_down"]').click()

        brand = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[1]').text
        item = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[2]').text
        inci_name = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[1]/span[2]').text
        count += 1

        try:
            ingredient_origin = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[3]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            ingredient_origin = 'null'
        try:
            function = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            function = 'null'
        try:
            benefit_claims = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            benefit_claims = 'null'
        try:
            description = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/p[3]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            description = 'null'
        try:
            labeling_claims = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            labeling_claims = 'null'
        try:
            compliance = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[6]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            compliance = 'null'
        try:
            hlb_value = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            hlb_value = 'null'
        try:
            end_uses = product.find_element('xpath', '/a/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            end_uses = 'null'
        try:
            cas_no = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            cas_no = 'null'
        try:
            chemical_name = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            chemical_name = 'null'
        try:
            synonyms = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[6]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            synonyms = 'null'
        try:
            chemical_family = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            chemical_family = 'null'
        try:
            features = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[7]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            features = 'null'
        try:
            grade = product.find_element('xpath', './a/div[2]/div/div[5]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            grade = 'null'

        dict = {
            'brand': brand,
            'item': item,
            'inci_name': inci_name,
            'ingredient_origin': ingredient_origin,
            'function': function,
            'benefit_claims': benefit_claims,
            'description': description,
            'labeling_claims': labeling_claims,
            'compliance': compliance,
            'hlb_value': hlb_value,
            'end_uses': end_uses,
            'cas_no': cas_no,
            'chemical_name': chemical_name,
            'synonyms': synonyms,
            'chemical_family': chemical_family,
            'features': features,
            'grade': grade
        }

        data.append(dict)
        print('Saving: ', dict['brand'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('cosmetics_data.csv', index=False)
```

output:

```
---------------------- page number: 1 ----------------------
Saving:  Sasol
Saving:  Arxada
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  Sasol
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Sasol
Saving:  Sasol
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  Arxada
Saving:  Sasol
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  Sasol
Saving:  VYNOVA
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  Salicylates and Chemicals Private Limited
Saving:  Sinerga S.p.A.
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  Ganeden, Inc.
Saving:  Miwon Commercial Company Ltd.
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Solabia Group
Saving:  Sytheon
Saving:  DAITO KASEI
Saving:  Sasol
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Sabinsa Cosmetics
---------------------- page number: 2 ----------------------
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Sytheon
Saving:  Sasol
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Alban Muller
Saving:  Arxada
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Chiba Flour Milling Co. Ltd
Saving:  DuPont Tate and Lyle BioProducts
Saving:  Momentive Performance Materials
Saving:  Lamberti Personal Care
Saving:  Solabia Group
Saving:  Salicylates and Chemicals Private Limited
Saving:  Kao Chemicals
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Active Concepts, LLC
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Kewpie Corporation
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  CP Kelco
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  DAITO KASEI
Saving:  Arxada
Saving:  Agrana
Saving:  Colonial Chemical
Saving:  Inolex
Saving:  Lamberti Personal Care
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Arxada
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  CP Kelco
Saving:  DSM
Saving:  SEPPIC INC
Saving:  Inolex
```

Few things to note:

1. The very first time we open the website, we need to click on the button `Accept All Cookies`.
2. Next, we can find all the 36 products on the page using the selector `div[data-cy="product-card"]`
3. You might notice that in a full window size, the page loads 4 products in a row and as we click on the `down-arrow` of 1st product to see more details, it also opens for the remaining 3 products on that row. So we just need to click once per row.
4. To implement the logic of clicking only once per row, we used a `count` variable as you can see in the code above.

Comment: you can find here the better version of the above solution: https://github.com/ajeet214/Web_Scraping_with_Selenium/blob/main/knowde_com.py

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I'm noticing that the dataset is only including what's on the screen. I the maximized window, that's six products now, which is an improvement. What can we add that would also require the browser to scroll alongside the scraper?

Comment: I think you need to correct the parsing, I see all the product details already there on the page after clicking the drop-down to expand. You just need to correctly parse it

Comment: I've updated the code on my mentioned GitHub link above, a more optimized version with better parsing logic, and, it scraps all the data from every product.